# Display custom module data using KnockOut Js in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I'm learning the `knockout js` to display in my custom module data. For this, I have tried below code the controller is successfully running, but it's not showing my data.

my code is:

**training_index_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Learning\Training\Block\KnockOut" before="-" cacheable="false" template="Learning_Training::list.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="knockouts" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Learning_Training/js/view/knockouts</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Controller\Index\View.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Training\Controller\Index;

class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('Welcome to Knock Out!..');
        return $resultPage;
    }


}
```

**Block\KnockOut.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Training\Block;

class KnockOut extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{

    /**
     * @var array|\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface[]
     */
    protected $layoutProcessors;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $layoutProcessors = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->jsLayout = isset($data['jsLayout']) && is_array($data['jsLayout']) ? $data['jsLayout'] : [];
        $this->layoutProcessors = $layoutProcessors;
    }

    public function getJsLayout()
    {
        foreach ($this->layoutProcessors as $processor) {
            $this->jsLayout = $processor->process($this->jsLayout);
        }
        return \Zend_Json::encode($this->jsLayout);
    }

}
```

**Training\view\frontend\web\js\view\knockouts.js**

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'mage/url',
    'mage/storage'
], function ($, ko, Component, urlBuilder,storage) {
    'use strict';

    var knockout = "";

    return Component.extend({

        defaults: {
            template: 'Learning_Training/knockouts'
        },

        initialize: function () {

            this._super();
            this.knockouts();

        },

        knockouts:function(){
            knockout = ko.observable("Welcome to Knockout JS! :)");
           return knockout;
        }

    });

});
```

**Training\view\frontend\web\template\knockouts.html**

```
 <h1 data-bind="text: knockouts"></h1>
```

**Training\view\frontend\templates\list.phtml**

```
 <?php /** @var $block \Learning\Training\Block\KnockOut */ ?>

<!--<h1><!?php /*echo $block->getTitle(); */?></h1>-->

<div id="block-knockouts" data-bind="scope:'knockouts'" class="block">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#block-knockouts": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        }
    }
</script>
</div>
```

[image]

Is it the correct way? or I went wrong somewhere?

Please through me right direction.

Comment: Any error are getting in console? Also please dont keep space before click function in your html file in data-bind attribute.

Comment: Please verify path for Learning/Training/view/frontend/web/js and view/frontend/web/template/knockout.html file.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Yes above files are the same path. still not getting.

Comment: have you create web/template and web/js folder right?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Yes, see above thread. that's my code.

Comment: in your controller you doesnt return as json in traineelist.php just return as return json_encode($TData);

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Sorry forgot to remove. Truly I removed yesterday in mine code.

Comment: whats your list.phtml file code please share

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya see my thread updated. You can find the code last before image in my thread.

Comment: @SohelRana any help on this?

Comment: whats the issue you faced now?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya see my thread updated with coding. It is showing the coding in frontend.

Comment: just run upgrade and deploy command

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya still showing `function (){
 knockout = ko.observable("Welcome to Knockout JS! :)");
 return knockout;
 }` coding part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All good your example code except **training_index_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Learning\Training\Block\KnockOut" before="-" cacheable="false" template="Learning_Training::list.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="knockouts" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Learning_Training/js/view/knockout</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear cache. Now you can able to see html content from **Training\view\frontend\web\template\knockout.html**

**[Update]**

Added following line for changing h1 text:

```
knockouts: ko.observable("Welcome to Knockout JS! :)"),
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it showing code in frontend. see my thread has updated the code with the screenshot.

Comment: Download file from here -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnvh7k583a0iehv/knockoutjs.zip?dl=0

Comment: After setup, URL -> ../stackexchange/index/view

Comment: Yes, now it's working fine. If I want to display simple text to `h1` tag (other than this like return the simple text from js to HTML file) how can? Can you have an example plz..?

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a function for property `knockouts` instead of a value like `ko.observable('Test')`, you should edit your component template like this:

Training\view\frontend\web\template\knockouts.html

```
<h1 data-bind="text: knockouts()"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function scope variable

Training\view\frontend\web\js\view\knockouts.js

```
define(['jquery','ko','uiComponent','mage/url','mage/storage'], function ($, ko, Component, urlBuilder,storage) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Learning_Training/knockouts',
                knockout: ko.observable("Welcome to Knockout JS! :)")
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },
            knockouts:function(){
                var self = this;
                return self.knockout();
            }
        });
    });
```

Then update the following code in the template file

Training\view\frontend\web\template\knockouts.html

```
<h1 data-bind="text: knockouts()"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller return pass as null,

```
 public function execute()
    {
        if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            $TList = $this->_trainingFactory->create()->load($id);

            $TData = [
                'training_id' => $TList->getTrainingId(),
                'firstname' => $TList->getFirstName(),
                'lastname' => $TList->getLastName(),
                'email' => $TList->getEmail()
            ];

            return json_encode($TData);
        }
    }
```

pass return as array of your dynamic data as above.

Update::

pass template as below way,

```
<?php /** @var $block \Learning\Training\Block\KnockOut */ ?>

<h1><?php echo $block->getTitle(); ?></h1>
    <div id="knockouts-div" data-bind="scope:'knockouts'">

        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
           "#knockouts-div": {
                 "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                     "components": {
                         "knockouts": {
                             "component": "Learning_Training/js/view/knockout"
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
        </script>

    <script>
    require([
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
    ], function(url, blockLoader) {
        blockLoader("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>");
        return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>');
    })
    </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes modified the `TraineeList` controller will call after **Get Training List** button clicked. HTML code is not showing in the page see my thread screenshot.